# i have already catched declared and catched exception but still there is an error

Tags: java, exception

```
class HelloWorld extends Exception {
    HelloWorld(String s) {
        System.out.println("helllo" + s);
    }
}

class myclass {
    void go() throws HelloWorld {
        System.out.println("my mom");
    }
}

public class ting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            myclass h= new myclass();
            h.go();
        } catch(HelloWorld e) {
            throw new HelloWorld("world");
        }
    }
}
```

I read that, we always need to declare an exception till we catch it. As above, I am using custom exception `HelloWorld` and when I throw this exception in other class i.e. myclass.Moreover, I catched this exception in the main method. Why it's not working?

```
o/p : ting.java:17: error: unreported exception HelloWorld; must be caught or declared to be thrown
         throw new HelloWorld("world");
         ^
1 error
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Where are you catching `HelloWorld` thrown inside the `catch` block?

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis : yes i am catching in catch block

Comment: You are catching and rethrowing, but the rethrown one is not caught.

Comment: If you catch an exception only to rethrow it later, you'll still have an error.

Comment: A catch block cannot catch exceptions thrown inside itself.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you're throwing the *exception* from the `catch` block.

Solutions:

- Declare your `main` to be `throws HelloWorld`:
  `public static void main(String[] args) throws HelloWorld`
- Surround it with `try-catch`.. again, but that'll be very weird:

---

```
catch(HelloWorld e){
   try {
       throw new HelloWorld("world");
       } catch (HelloWorld e1) { }
   }
}
```

Note: You better name your *exception* `HelloWorldExcption`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you don't have a solid grasp of what exceptions are trying to accomplish, or I absolutely don't understand the way you've abstracted your code into this example.

I'll try to create a similar example that should explain how exceptions are used most of the time:

```
public class MyClass {
    class UnexpectedException extends Exception {
        UnexpectedException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        try {
            System.out.println(c.computeMessage());
        } catch (UnexpectedException e) {
            System.err.println("Something unexpected happened: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String computeMessage() throws UnexpectedException {
        // Try to compute a message here, but something goes wrong so:
        throw new UnexpectedException("Oh no, could not compute the message!");
    }
}
```

Exceptions are thrown when something exceptional happens, and in order to inform the programmer that exceptional situations can occur, method declarations can declare that they might throw a certain exception.

The programmer can then "catch" that potential thrown exception to provide debugging or recovery code in the exceptional circumstance that the exception occurs.

I hope this clarifies what exceptions are for and how they should be used. Let me know if you have more questions.

Edit: To address the error you're having, if you move the line `throw new HelloWorld("world")` from your catch block to the go method, your example should work.

Comment: but i want know , suppose you created your own exception. how you will declare that exception and how you will catch that excetion?

Comment: moreover , declaring exception means you are using keyword "throws" in method like "somemethod throws Myexception1 ,Myexception2" and i must catch these declared exception in my main() method or other method where i can catch them????? is that all true??

Comment: Both situations are in the example I've given: UnexpectedException is a custom Exception that's being created and the computeMessage method declares that it throws it, you could rename it MegaAwesomePersonalClassThatWeUseToThrowWhenWeirdShitHappens and the code would still look the same (given that all occurences of UnexpectedException are replaced with that).

Comment: Declaring Exceptions does mean something like that indeed, whether you have to catch an exception or not is a more complicated matter, you can always rethrow it, and RuntimeExceptions never need to be caught, if you want to know more about that you could google "java checked vs unchecked exceptions"

Answer (score 0):

You are already catching the `HelloWorld` exception declared as being throwable by the `go()` method. You don't want to catch it and re-throw it in most cases. Instead of catching the exception thrown by `go()` you could declare that main() throws the exception, and then you don't have to catch it - though this is not good practice. Also, exceptions should be named:

```
HelloWorldException
```

and not: `HelloWorld`.

Comment: first of all, you mean that i remove "void go() throws HelloWorld" to "void go()" but why?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I mean that you don't re-throw the exception once you catch it, inside the catch block of your try-catch.